# Enum class initialization with int

Tags: c++, enums, initialization, c++17

I found out some interesting thing when I programming:

```
enum class Foo {
  FOO_THING,
  FOO_TOO
};

int main() {
  Foo foo{1};    // It is OK
  Foo foo2(1);   // It is an invalid
}
```

Could you tell me, why `foo{1}` is OK for compiler, and why `foo2(1)` is invalid ?

Compiler GCC (`g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-21ubuntu1~16.04) 7.3.0`) says:

```
$ g++ -Wall -std=c++17 foo.cpp

  error: cannot convert ‘int’ to ‘Foo’ in initialization
  Foo foo2(1);
```

I really want to know underlying mechanics. :)))

**Edit:** Maybe it is some compiler bug...

Comment: For the record VS2015 gives error on both.

Comment: I add a note about compiler version

Comment: Apparently, this is supported since C++17. But I don't know which change is responsable for enabling it. However, `Foo foo2(1)` fails because it's a constructor call and an enum class does not have a constructor taking an int.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C++17-specific [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) has the following for braced initializer

> Otherwise, if T is a enumeration type that is either scoped or
>   unscoped with fixed underlying type, and if the braced-init-list has
>   only one initializer, and if the conversion from the initializer to
>   the underlying type is non-narrowing, and if the initialization is
>   direct-list-initialization, then the enumeration is initialized with
>   the result of converting the initializer to its underlying type.

So `foo` seems to be conforming valid C++17, but `foo2` being not braced initialized is not valid.

Answer (score 5):

To understand the reasons why the two syntax are not both legit you must consider that scoped enums were introduced with standard c++11 to enforce static type checking and have scoped identifiers (i.e. no name pollution anymore).

`Foo foo(1)` is not working because implicit conversion from integer type to scoped enum is forbidden, otherwise you lose the benefit of scoped enums, and to avoid conflicts during overload resolution.

When using `Foo foo{1}` you are using [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) that was introduced with c++11 too, but got an upgrade with c++17, that consist in implicit conversion from int value to enum as reported [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), if a set of requirements are satisfied:

> Both scoped enumeration types and unscoped enumeration types whose
> underlying type is fixed can be initialized from an integer without a
> cast, using list initialization, if all of the following is true:
>
> 1. the initialization is direct-list-initialization
> 2. the initializer list has only a single element
> 3. the enumeration is either scoped or unscoped with underlying type fixed
> 4. the conversion is non-narrowing.
>
> This makes it possible to introduce new integer types (e.g. SafeInt) that enjoy the same existing calling conventions as their underlying integer
> types, even on ABIs that penalize passing/returning structures by
> value.

This syntax is safe and will not interfere with legacy code (written before c++11) because both scoped enums and list-initialization did not exist at the time. Furthermore, as reported in the quote, this enables the use of new integer types (like those of the SafeInt library) without the need to force a static cast for enum types in code that conforms to modern c++ syntax.